# SequelizeJS: Batch setting foreign key

Tags: javascript, sql, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I have two models, `Article` and `ArticleGroup`:

```
sequelize.define('article', {
  GROUP_CODE: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  ...
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      this.belongsTo(models.articleGroup);
    },
  },
});

...

sequelize.define('articleGroup', {
  GROUP_CODE: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  ...
});
```

I'm working with legacy data where the connection between those two is made with the `GROUP_CODE` field. I've added a foreign key to the `article` model. The problem is when I try to update that foreign key. This is the code with which I'm trying to accomplish that:

```
let db = require('../models');

db.articleGroup.findAll().then((groups) => {
  groups.forEach((group) => {
    db.article.update({groupArticleId: group.id}, {where: {GROUP_CODE: group.GROUP_CODE}});
  });
});
```

With this code I get a bunch of:

```
...
Executing (default): UPDATE `article` SET `updatedAt`='2017-08-05 12:43:02' WHERE `GROUP_CODE` = '6'
Executing (default): UPDATE `article` SET `updatedAt`='2017-08-05 12:43:02' WHERE `GROUP_CODE` = '11'
Executing (default): UPDATE `article` SET `updatedAt`='2017-08-05 12:43:02' WHERE `GROUP_CODE` = '1'
...
```

It's updating the `updatedAt` but not the `groupArticleId` field. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that did the association was the following:

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

Which was never done, because none of my models had the `associate` property. Changing the models from:

```
sequelize.define('article', {
  ...
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      this.belongsTo(models.articleGroup);
    },
  },
});
```

to:

```
let Article = sequelize.define('article', {
  ...
});
Article.associate = function(models) {
  this.belongsTo(models.articleGroup);
}

return Article;
```

Fixed my issue since now the models have the `associate` property and can be properly associated e.g. Sequelize will create getters and setters for the foreign keys.